# How to implement diff for tree of strings?

Tags: javascript, string, tree, diff

How to implement a function that interprets the difference between 2 trees of strings? For example:

```
diff(["aaa","bbb",["ccc","ddd"],"eee"],
     ["aaa","bbx",["ccc","ddd"]]);
```

This function should report the edit on "bbb" and the removal of "eee". How to implement such function?

Comment: By iterating over the arrays and comparing the elements. This implementation might give you some idea: http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/.

Comment: Start with the keyword `function` followed by a space, and then a valid identifier of your choosing to use as the function name. Then you'll need an opening parentheses, followed by two more valid identifiers, separated by a comma. After that, you'll need a closing parentheses followed by an opening curly brace. I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: @thesystem I don't get the reason for the irony. Also, downvoters might care to explain?

Comment: @Dokkat: You're getting downvoted because you haven't shown any effort in solving this problem yourself. At this stage, "how to implement" is effectively "implement this for me". You've asked 180 questions so far. I think you should know how it works. But if not, please read this page carefully: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com

Comment: ...and that wasn't irony. Those were instructions for getting started. Since you've shown nothing, I must assume you need entry-level help.

Comment: Your assumption is almost correct, I'm asking for entry-level help on the diff problem, not on JavaScript. Is your point that I can't do so?

Comment: @Dokkat Apply something like [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) at each level? Although if the "deletions" can be ignored a paired comparison will get most of the way there. Deletions/insertions are the hard bit.

Comment: @thesystem also, you're probably mistaken on the need of explaining "what I have tried", as the most voted questions on Stack Overflow are direct and go straight to the point, without giving much details - which makes them more broad range and helpful to people with the same doubt - which is something I try to mimic on my questions.

Comment: @pst seems like a good starting point, thanks.

Comment: @Dokkat: Then why the JavaScript tag? And you didn't ask about philosophical approaches to the problem. You asked how to ***implement*** a function. So what have you tried? What research have you done? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to iterate an Array? Do you know how to compare values?

Comment: @thesystem because it targets JavaScript, which would implement this differently from, say, Haskell. I haven't "tried" much, and this is the point of the question: guiding me to the proper resources so I can try the right things. user1389596 and pst have perfectly done that without much effort. So what's the problem here? I believe this kind of question is perfectly valid. Is your point that it is not?

Comment: Yes, that's my point. *"...it targets JavaScript, which would implement this differently from, say, Haskell."* You said you're not asking for help on the JavaScript. If you're asking for help on the general algorithm, you should describe what research you've done, and what you're having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple textual diff, you could just transform each tree into a flat file.

Translate the nodes to lines, such that each subnode is prepended with tabs (one tab for each level of nesting).  Then run a diff on the two flat files.  Eg:

```
["aaa","bbb",["ccc","ddd"],"eee"]
```

becomes (escape tab and newline):

```
aaaa
bbb
    ccc
    ddd
eee
```

If you want a numeric measure, count the lines in the diff output.

If you want to get fancy, it can do it per node, but that's a lot of work depending on what the result is used for.